# Automate texture mapping in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to automate texture mapping on the mesh. As shown in the image, I have applied one texture (1024 X 1024 pixels) to two cubes, one cube with a big surface and second with a small surface. The texture is getting resized for both cubes differently as the image is scaled with respect to the UV coordinates. I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the ideal scale of the image for the surface. Like, if there is any equation between surface bounds, UV coordinates, and Size of the image.
[image]

Comment: There is an equation, yes. UV coordinate = texture size / object size

Comment: How to calculate texture size?

Comment: You don't calculate it, you either already know it or read it from the file. It's 1024 here, as you stated in your question. Since your object is probably not 1024 in size, you'll want to add a `pixels / unit` factor

Comment: The scale factor for texture is changing as per object again.
I have calculated it as follows:
Assumption: 1 unit = 1 meter in Three.js
small cube is of 50 inches, so 1.27 meter
big cube is of 100 inches, so 2.54 meter

uv = 1024/1.27  = 806

Comment: If the cube is twice as big, you need a UV coordinate of 0.5 instead of 1. The 806 is meaningless without establishing a relation between texture pixels and inches first. You have 1024/50 as pixels per inch, so you need 1024 / 100 * (50/1024) is 0.5

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a tiled texture (no seams when repeating), you could repeat the texture according to the size of the cube.

```
// depending on how you create the cube, the actual size of the cube is hidden either in
// the geometry, the transformation matrix (or object scale), or both. This should respect all.
var size = cube.geometry.boundingBox.getSize().multiply(cube.scale);

// adjust size of texture with `resolution` or some constant
var repeatFactor = resolution * size.x;

var texture = cube.material.map;
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( repeatFactor, repeatFactor );
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```